# Overwriting a function with prototype from an abstract class (typescript)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2013, abstract-class

my typescript class(base)

```
namespace customNamepsace
{
    export abstract class SomeAbstractClass
    {
     public SomeFunction()
        {
        //Some (standard)action
        }
    }
}
```

Inside some other class(overwriting a function):

```
class AnotherClass extends customNamepsace.SomeAbstractClass
{
        customNamepsace.SomeAbstractClass.prototype.SomeFunction=function()
        {
        //overwrite that (standard)action

        }
}
```

I get :

> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was
>   expected.

What to do here ?

Comment: I don't have any error message

Comment: Is this even supposed to work? I don't think TypeScript supports that...

Comment: Are you sure you really want to overwrite? Did you mean overRIDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *override* the behavior of `SomeFunction`, try this:

```
class AnotherClass extends customNamepsace.SomeAbstractClass
{
     public SomeFunction()
     {
        //Code to override the behavior of the base class
     }
}
```